# On Heroku in production, how can I copy database A to database B on command?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2, heroku, rails

From my local terminal, I can use the following commands to do what I need to do:

```
heroku pgbackups:capture --expire

heroku pgbackups:restore charcoal --confirm max-kiosk
```

However, I want to do this from the controller of my rails app, when the Version model is udpated. Locally, I'm using:

```
env = Rails.env
%x{pg_dump -Fc master_bankkiosk_#{env} > database.dump}
puts "I'm dumping..."
%x{pg_restore --clean -d bankkiosk_#{env} database.dump}
puts "I'm restoring..."
```

I have come to understand that running heroku commands on the heroku server do not work (because the toolbelt is not installed there ?)

I've tried to use pg_dump command on heroku server as well. I've read a few SO questions that seems similar but the OP are satisfied with answers that include `heroku pgbackups:blah`, and I can't use that.

Comment: @CraigRinger You were very helpful in my last question.  Just hoping you can take a look at this, too.

Comment: Not really - Rails and Heroku aren't hugely my scene.

Comment: Copied & pasted from http://stackoverflow.com/q/24742411/398670